# Is ASCII FBX export still supported?

Tags: export, .fbx

I was using ASCII FBX in my game engine, but can't seem to export that format any more from Blender (I just get Binary FBX when I use export FBX from the menu)

Is it still supported? Are there any alternative export plugins?

Thanks!